# При использовании request.getParameter() получаю null..

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, java-ee

Не могу понять почему при использовании request.getParameter("..."), я получаю null ?? [Пример туториала где используется та же конструкция..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gy2eEZhLihk)

Если кто сталкивался плиз хелп..

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstName"); System.out.println(firstname);
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastName");  System.out.println(lastname);
    String email = request.getParameter("emailAddress"); System.out.println(email);

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   }
}
```

```js
$("#sudmitId").click(function () {

    var firstName = $("[name=firstName]").val();
    var lastName = $("[name=lastName]").val();
    var emailAddress = $("[name=emailAddress]").val();

    var user = {

        firstName:this.firstName,
        lastName:this.lastName,
        emailAddress:this.emailAddress
    }

    $.ajax({

        url:"http://localhost:9090/Demo/Servlet",
        method:"post",
        data:user,
        contentType:"application/text",
        error:function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        },
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

    })

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>

<body>

<form>

    <label>FirstName: </label>
    <input name="firstName" type="text"><br>
    <label>LastName: </label>
    <input name="lastName" type="text"><br>
    <label>Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="emailAddress"><br>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id = "sudmitId" value="Send!">

</form>
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="formhandler.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно отправляете форму на сервер. Если вы хотите, чтобы данные формы можно было достать через `request.getParameter()`, их нужно отправлять на сервер не c `contentType:"application/text"`, а с `contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost:8443/Demo/Servlet",
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: user
});
```

Если же вы хотите слать данные именно в JSON, то, во-первых, нужно сериализовать посылаемый объект в строку:

```
data: JSON.stringify(user)
```

А во-вторых, читать его на сервере нужно не через `request.getParameter()`, а через `request.getInputStream()`:

```
InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
String data = s.next();
// Опционально: десериализуем полученный JSON в Map. Здесь я использовал библиотеку Gson.
Map map = new Gson().fromJson(data, Map.class);
```